# Custom training Tensorflow on Sagemaker: WARNING keras.py:603 cannot save layer values during forward pass with tf.function

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras, batch-processing, amazon-sagemaker

I am training a custom model with a custom layer using Tensorflow on Sagemaker. It runs smoothly local, no errors, no warnings. When I run it on Sagemaker, it produces many warnings, all the same:

```
2021-01-22 15:20:26.660 xxxx.xxxx.compute.internal:32 WARNING keras.py:603] cannot save layer values during forward pass with tf.function
```

I am not sure if this is something to be worried about. Does someone have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

This warning is logged smdebug/tensorflow/keras.py [from changeset 9ad5d8251dfa3cab2be494cd49f06678a6a84a4e, line 603](https://github.com/awslabs/sagemaker-debugger/blob/9ad5d8251dfa3cab2be494cd49f06678a6a84a4e/smdebug/tensorflow/keras.py#L603) from 2020-12-08.

In [changeset da3b4e30b09dda4813c7b6b3bef0e7fb0c8243cf, line 604](https://github.com/awslabs/sagemaker-debugger/blob/da3b4e30b09dda4813c7b6b3bef0e7fb0c8243cf/smdebug/tensorflow/keras.py#L604) from 2020-12-23 the warning was removed, so apparently the authors decided the warning is redundant.